# multiplying a 1D array by items in a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to ask a question about multiplying items in a 1D array with items returned from a function that are a matrix in the form of a 3D array.

I have the following array of numbers named `mass_array`:

```
array([12.0107 ,  1.00794, 12.0107 ,  1.00794, 12.0107 ,  1.00794,
   12.0107 ,  1.00794, 12.0107 ,  1.00794, 12.0107 ,  1.00794])
```

and the following 3D array named `coordinate_array`:

```
array([[ 0.     ,  1.40272,  0.     ],
   [ 0.     ,  2.49029,  0.     ],
   [-1.21479,  0.70136,  0.     ],
   [-2.15666,  1.24515,  0.     ],
   [-1.21479, -0.70136,  0.     ],
   [-2.15666, -1.24515,  0.     ],
   [ 0.     , -1.40272,  0.     ],
   [ 0.     , -2.49029,  0.     ],
   [ 1.21479, -0.70136,  0.     ],
   [ 2.15666, -1.24515,  0.     ],
   [ 1.21479,  0.70136,  0.     ],
   [ 2.15666,  1.24515,  0.     ]])
```

I am going to perform a calculation on each of these lines (which correspond to an atom on Benzene) to return a 3x3 matrix using a function called `buildi`, which performs calculations on a 1x3 matrix.

I want to multiply each corresponding item in `mass_array` by the result of the `buildi` function with its corresponding line on `coordinate_array`:

e.g.

for line 1 of both arrays multiplied together:

```
12.0107 * buildi([ 0.     ,  1.40272,  0.     ])
```

and then for line 2 of both arrays:

```
1.00794 * buildi([ 0.     ,  2.49029,  0.     ])
```

all the way down to the very last line,

```
1.00794 * buildi([ 2.15666,  1.24515,  0.     ])
```

and add the results of each of these multiplications to a final array.

My attempt at doing this ended up as such:

```
def inertia_matrix(array1, array2):
inertia_molecule = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])
for atom in array2:
    inertia_molecule = inertia_molecule + buildi(atom)
print(inertia_molecule)
```

The problem, however, is that I can't 'map' the molecular weight to the corresponding line in the for loop.

My intention was to attempt something like:

```
for atom in array2 and weight in array1:
    inertia_molecule = inertia_molecule + weight*buildi(atom)
```

but I couldn't work anything out that would fit such a purpose. 
I attempted to use the zip function but I couldn't make it accommodate the `weight*buildi(atom)` part of my code.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you give some clarity what do you want to find?

Comment: @komatiraju032 i want to match up the two different arrays so I can multiply each corresponding item in the same position in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The `zip` function is exactly made for this usecase:

```py
inertia_molecules = []
for mass, atom in zip(mas_array, coordinate_array):
    inertia_molecules.append( mass * buildi(atom) )
```

Now the list `inertia_molecules` holds a list of all 3x3 matrices produced by the calculations.

(If you are dealing with a large list, you might want to pre-allocate the space for speed and then access the individual cells instead appending new values to the end)